# C function for returning custom length char

Tags: c, string, function, for-loop

Please be aware that I am new to C. I am coding a function that receives a number and returns a `*char` formed by `'*'` of the received length. i.e:

```
createHiddenName(6)//returns "******"
createHiddenName(4)//returns "****"
```

I've coded it like this, but it's not working:

```
char *createHiddenName(int length)
{
    char *hidden[length];//
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        hidden[i] = '*';
    }
    return *hidden;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: `Please be aware that I am new to C`....uummmm..why?

Comment: `char *hidden[length];`...you don;t need that

Comment: `return *hidden;`....what? why?

Comment: Don't return anything, pass a buffer to fill.

Comment: Compile with all warnings on. Take the compiler's warning serious. Fix the code until no more warnings are issued. Do not blindly "cast away" warnings.

Comment: Please post the function as an answer, if you don't mind. How can I consume it?

Comment: Get a good beginner's book. Learning C from trial and error can lead to a disaster. Where are the guys who have all the links?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Because the amount of time I dedicated to C is less than a day, thus it can be inferred, by definition, that novelty impregnates my idosyncrasy regarding C Programming Language, being new to it.

Comment: @DeiDei - [I got you covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Don't forget that a *string* needs a '\0' character at the end... you will need to make sure there is space for that! (Some programmer dude mentions this in his answer I just noticed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use dynamic memory allocation as below

```
char *createHiddenName(int length)
{
  char *hidden = malloc((length+1) * sizeof(char));
  if(hidden == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    hidden[i] = '*';
  }
  hidden[i] = '\0'; //Null terminated string
  return hidden;
}
```

Make sure you need to free the memory after done with `hidden` variable.

```
char *ptr = createHiddenName(10);
//....
// Use ptr
//....
// done ? then free it 
free(ptr);
ptr = NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.

Answer (score 4):

Two major problems:

```
char *hidden[length];
```

This defines `hidden` as an array of *pointers* to `char`. It could be an array of *strings*, not a string itself.

Then you *attempt* to return a pointer to this array, but the array is a local variable that goes out of scope and will cease to exist once the function returns. Using the returned pointer will then lead to *undefined behavior*.

The simplest solution is to pass the buffer to be filled as an argument. Something like

```
char *createHiddenName(int length, char *hidden)
{
    ...
    return hidden;
}
```

Of course remember to create a buffer big enough to hold the full string *including* the null terminator (which you don't add now).

Answer (score 0):

In your original approach, you have,

```
   char *hidden[length]; // Why would you like to have an array of pointers?
   return *hidden; // Wrong because unless 'malloc'ated, a pointer inside the function will not work after the return, Consider what happens if the function stack is cleared.
```

Instead you can follow the below approach.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char hidden_name[100]; 
// global char array for storing the value returned from function
char *createHiddenName(int length)
{
            char temp[length+1];
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        temp[i] = '*';
                        }
                temp[i]='\0'; // Null terminating  temp
            strncpy(hidden_name,temp,(size_t)(length+1));
            //Remember temp perishes after function, so copy temp to hidden_name
            return hidden_name;
}


int main(){
printf("Hidden Name : %s\n",createHiddenName(6));
return 0;
}
```